# Java Recursion method

Tags: java, recursion

The below method return 5 if you give n = 20.
My question is how is 1 incremented on each iteration?

```
mystery(10) + 1 
= mystery(5) + 2 
= mystery(2) + 3 
= mystery(1) + 4 
= mystery(0) + 5 = 5.
```

I am having some hard time with recursion.

```
public static int mystery(int n){
   if(n <= 0){
        return 0;
   }else{
       return mystery(n / 2 ) + 1;
   }
}
```

Comment: My question is how does 1 is incremented on each iteration?  Please clarify.

Comment: Step through this in a debugger - all will be answered

Comment: Simply put you could think that it returns `ln(n) + 1`.

Comment: @devnull that should be `ln(n)/ln(2) + 1`, or `log-base-2(n) + 1`

Comment: @ajb I thought that base 2 was obvious.

Comment: @devnull `ln` means "log to the base _e_", period.  It stands for "natural log".  `log` can sometimes be ambiguous and could mean base-_e_, base-10, or base-something-else-obvious.  But not `ln`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding how recursive functions work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676961/understanding-how-recursive-functions-work)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
mystery(20) = mystery(10) + 1
mystery(20) = (mystery(5) + 1) + 1
mystery(20) = ((mystery(2) + 1) + 1) + 1
mystery(20) = (((mystery(1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1
mystery(20) = ((((mystery(0) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1
```

and we know that `mystery(0)` = 0.

```
mystery(20) = ((((0 + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1
mystery(20) = (((1 + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1
mystery(20) = ((2 + 1) + 1) + 1
mystery(20) = (3 + 1) + 1
mystery(20) = 4 + 1
mystery(20) = 5
```

Or, simply put, we get `1+1+1+1+1=5`

Pretty good video on recursion here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mv9NEXX1VHc

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the code should make it obvious that:

```
mystery(20) = mystery(10) + 1
mystery(10) = mystery(5) + 1
mystery(5) = mystery(2) + 1
mystery(2) = mystery(1) + 1
mystery(1) = mystery(0) + 1
mystery(0) = 0
```

Now go back and plug in all the values, e.g.

```
mystery(1) = mystery(0) + 1 = 0 + 1 = 1
mystery(2) = mystery(1) + 1 = 1 + 1 = 2
mystery(5) = mystery(2) + 1 = 2 + 1 = 3, etc.
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time `mystery()` is called, it returns the value returned by calling itself, plus 1. So, for every call, the returned number gets incremented by 1.